# NotFoundError when dumping a model using pickle

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pickle

I am trying to save a model in a new file if the model does not yet exists. When I try to dump the model in a new file, the file does get created but the trained model does not get dumped with it.
This is my code:

```
if os.path.exists("trained_model.pickle"):
    print("loading trained model")
    with open("trained_model.pickle","rb") as file:
        pickle.load(model)
else:
    print('creating and training a new model')
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4)

    with open("trained_model.pickle","wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(model, file))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in the above code is in the pickle.load(model) line. It should be pickle.load(file)

```
    import tensorflow as tf 
    import os
    import pickle
    if os.path.exists("trained_model.pickle"):
        print("loading trained model")
        with open("trained_model.pickle","rb") as file:
            pickle.load(file)
    else:
        print('creating and training a new model')
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4)
    
        with open("trained_model.pickle","wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(model, file)
        with open("trained_model.pickle", "rb") as infile:
           test_model = pickle.load(infile)
        test_model.summary()
```